# Not able to distinguish injectable objects in the Bridge design pattern with Spring boot framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am not sure how I can inject the abstract class and its extensions in the bridge design pattern in Spring. Let's consider the classic bridge design pattern example of shape:

Color.java

```
public interface Color {

  String fill();
}
```

Blue.java

```
@Service("Blue")
public class Blue implements Color {
  @Override
  public String fill() {
    return "Color is Blue";
  }
}
```

Red.java

```
@Service("Red")
public class Red implements Color {
  @Override
  public String fill() {
    return "Color is Red";
  }
}
```

Shape.java

```
public abstract class Shape {
  protected Color color;

  @Autowired
  private Something something;

  @Value(${foo.bar})
  private String fooBar;

  public Shape(Color color){
    this.color = color;
  }

  abstract public String draw();
}
```

Square.java

```
public class Square extends Shape {

  public Square(Color color) {
    super(color);
  }

  @Override
  public String draw() {
    return "Square drawn. " + color.fill();
  }
}
```

Triangle.java

```
public class Triangle extends Shape {

  public Triangle(Color color) {
    super(color);
  }

  @Override
  public String draw() {
    return "Triangle drawn. " + color.fill();
  }
}
```

BridgeApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BridgeApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BridgeApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class BridgeController {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("Red")
  private Color red;

  @GetMapping("/red")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public String redSquare() {
    Shape square = new Square(red);
    return square.draw();
  }

}
```

The problem arises when we would like to inject the abstract class `Shape` or its extensions like `Square` or `Triangle`. Because of the fact that constructor accepts a Color object and we cannot decide if the `Color` is a type of `Red` or `Blue` (That's the whole point of using Bridge design pattern here) then we cannot define `Shape` or its extensions to be a Spring Bean because there will be multiple beans of the type `Color` available. The easy workaround is like what I did to construct the object directly instead of injecting it. However, now there will be all challenges regarding any value I am injecting or any other Bean I would like to inject in the `Shape` class or its extensions (like `fooBar` or `something`) because the corresponding classes are constructed manually.

One solution is to start dealing with the manual injection that will create a lot of unnecessary complexity with the value and bean injections and it's not a clean solution at all. Like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/inject-properties-value-non-spring-class) or referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null). So I was wondering if there is a clean way of having some form of Bridge design pattern in the Spring framework or due to the Spring limitations, there is none.

Answer (score 0):

You can take bean from `ApplicationContext`.....But you need to pass color to take bean....

Here is one Example :

```
@RestController
public class BridgeController {

    private final Color red;
    private final Shape redSquareShape;

    public BridgeController(@Qualifier("Red") Color red,
                            ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.red = red;
        this.redSquareShape = (Shape) applicationContext.getBean("square", red);
    }

    @GetMapping("/red")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String redSquare() {
        Shape square = new Square(red);
        return square.draw();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do I need to define the Shape or Square to be a bean now? As soon as I define the Shape to be a bean then the Shape contractor creates the ambiguity.

Comment: Here shape create with color constructor. You can take square or trinagle also. Give it in type casting. From applicationcontext you can take any bean by passing bean name

Comment: How should it now if the "square" is referring to class Square? Do we need a qualifier for that as well?

Comment: First uppercase  be small letter rest of all will be same

Comment: I have to actually test it but, I don't think it will resolve the whole problem, Still, I need to manually construct the "Square" which is going to cause some issues with injecting "Something" and "fooBar" because we cannot have a bean for "Square"

Comment: I've just tested it. If I define "Square" and "Triangle" to be a bean then it gives me type ambiguity on their constructor (as it accepts "Shape" and they are two beans of type Shape available". If I don't define them to be a bean, it does not work as it complains that no bean with the name of "square" exists.

Comment: Here is the error I am getting: 

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'square' available

I have noticed if I put all classes in a single package it passes this stage, but when they are placed in different packages neither this approach nor referring to the bean by using fqdn work for me.

Comment: if you keep them differenct packages then give all packages in @ComponentScan in main method class... Its another issue.not related to this

Comment: I did actually it wasn't helpful.